# How to call a function in shared library using Lua

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

I have a shared library where I have some functions. I want to access them by getting their signature using luajit.

I have a libtest_c.so --> /usr/local/lib

lua --> /usr/local/bin

> require("test_c")

stdin:1: module 'test_c' not found:

```
no field package.preload['test_c']
no file './test_c.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.4/test_c.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/test_c.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/test_c/init.lua'
no file './test_c.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/test_c.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00404270

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Call a function in shared library using Lua:**

http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html

```
local lib = ffi.load('some.dll')
ffi.cdef[[
  void hello (void);
]]
lib.hello()
```